# Multiple counts in one query

Tags: php, mysql, count

This query doesn't work. Can someone help me please?

```
$query = "SELECT 
    COUNT(WHERE Name='george') AS george_total,
    COUNT(WHERE Name='michael') AS michael_total,
    COUNT(WHERE Name='mike') AS mike_total 
FROM users WHERE Banned IS NOT '1' AND Active='yes' AND Logins>1 AND Registered_to_forum='1'";

$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo "
    We found $row['george_total'] people with the name 'George' in our database,
    $row['michael_total'] with the name Michael
    and $row['mike_total'] with the name Mike.
";
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` statement and either `COUNT` or `SUM`.

The `COUNT` version is below. `COUNT` only counts `NOT NULL` values so you can use any Non Null column or constant instead of 1.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Name='george' THEN 1 END) AS george_total,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Name='michael' THEN 1 END) AS michael_total,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Name='mike' THEN 1 END) AS mike_total /*.... rest of query*/
```

The `SUM` version is

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Name='george' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS george_total,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Name='michael' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS michael_total,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Name='mike' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS mike_total /*.... rest 
                                                                   of query*/
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't return the amount of for example george's, it only returns 1 or 0. Not 10 george's or something like that.

Comment: @Jordy - You must only have one george then. Both queries work fine. Maybe you are excluding them because of your `where` clause?